# Finding a non-cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What is the unique non-cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$? At first I thought $\langle (1,0), (0,p) \rangle$ but this has order $p$ no?

Comment: You're probably conflating it with $\langle(1,p)\rangle$, which is also a subgroup of $C_p\times C_{p^2}$ and _does_ have order $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $\langle (1,0),(0,p)\rangle$ has order $p^2$.
It consists of all the elements $(i, pj)$ for $i = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, p-1$ and $j = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, p-1$.

Comment: sorry I saw my stupid mistake now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct, since $\langle(1,0)\rangle$ contains $p$ elements and $\langle(0,p)\rangle$ also contains $p$ elements (as subgroup of $\mathbb(Z)_p\times\mathbb(Z)_{p^2}$ of course). Therefore $\langle(1,0),(0,p)\rangle$ contains $p^2$ elements.

Comment: This isn't quite enough by itself - note that e.g. $\langle(1,0)\rangle$ has $p$ elements and $\langle(2,0)\rangle$ _also_ has $p$ elements, but $\langle(1,0),(2,0)\rangle$ certainly doesn't have $p^2$. You also have to show that e.g. $(0,p)\not\in\langle(1,0)\rangle$.

Comment: yeah my bad, but it seemed obvious enough to me, since $\langle(1,0)\rangle\cap\langle(0,p)\rangle=\{(0,0)\}$.